# Correct Grammar in School Tagline

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Which of the following school taglines is grammatically correct? Or, could both be correct? If both, which is clearer?

Option 1: Enter to learn, empower to serve
Option 2: Enter to learn, empowered to serve

Comment: What's the last part supposed to mean?

Comment: You mean come here for the learning and leave with the power to serve others?

Comment: 'which is clearer' means which expresses the idea that students enter the school to learn but are empowered to serve when they leave.

Comment: Enter to learn, graduate to serve? Enter. Learn. Graduate. Serve?

Comment: @YosefBaskin "Enter to learn, graduate to serve" is what the tagline intends to express. The school has option 1 currently, but something tells me that something might not be right about it, grammatically. I am of the opinion that option 2 is the correct grammar but I am no language expert. If the grammar is incorrect, I can suggest adding 'ed' but not to change an entire word.

Comment: If you can change two letters and no more, you are either working for Nazis or feeding your own assumption that you'll get fired for suggesting an edit of an entire word. Empowered? Not. You can improve BS marketing slogans without blaming bad grammar.

Comment: I just want to stick to the  grammar of the tagline. I have no intention of telling a school board to change a word in their tagline. I just want to focus on whether the state is okay as is or should be corrected.

Comment: People are saying that neither alternative offered is appropriate. 'Enter to learn' is [prospective] pupil-orientated; 'empower to serve' is part of the school's mission statement. The two don't belong side by side.

Comment: To put Edwin Ashcroft's point another way: both parts appear to be suggestions or commands (verb in the imperative mood), but joining them thus with a comma is grammatically inappropriate and misleading if they are addressed to separate parties: the first part to the prospective student, the second to the institution itself. If the school intends to declare its mission as educating students for roles in which *they* will empower and thus serve *others,* then the thing makes more sense; but then, how many readers are likely to interpret it that way without further guidance?

Comment: "Enter to learn, _be empowered_ to serve"?

Comment: @KateBunting ’s version above is the only way to save this, given your constraints. It really does need an entire rewrite though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Enter to learn" is syntactically an imperative, though pragmatically it acts as an offer rather than a command. For the sake of parallelism, then, the imperative "empower to serve" would be correct. But that doesn't really make any sense; as an imperative, it would imply that you want your students to empower *other people* to serve. But this can easily be corrected:

> Enter to learn, **be** empowered to serve